# Heredoc for nested command in bash

Tags: bash, ssh, nested, heredoc

I need to ssh into a machine and execute a bunch of commands under `sudo bash`. Here is what I've tried:

```
sshpass -p "vagrant" ssh vagrant@33.33.33.100 "sudo bash -i -c <<EOF
    echo
    ls
    echo
EOF"
```

But it throws me `'bash: -c: option requires an argument\n'`. How can I fix this?

Comment: The `-c` option requires an argument in the command line, not a heredoc. A heredoc is an input redirection.

Comment: Just remove `-c` and it will work fine.

Comment: In addition, `-i` means 'interactive', does it not? How is it possible if you are redirecting its standard input?

Comment: @anubhava, thank you, it solved my problem! Can you write an answer so that I can accept it? Also, I would like more details about why it wasn't working in the first place, if you have the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `-c` from your command line to make it accept heredoc:

```
sshpass -p "vagrant" ssh vagrant@33.33.33.100 "sudo bash <<EOF
    echo
    ls
    echo
EOF"
```

Also you may remove `-i` (interactive) option too.

`bash -c` expects you to provide all commands on command line so this may work too:

```
sshpass -p "vagrant" ssh vagrant@33.33.33.100 "sudo bash -c 'echo; ls; echo'"
```