# Bash return code error handling when using heredoc input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heredoc

**Motivation**

I'm in a situation where I have to run multiple bash commands with a single bash invocation without the possibility to write a full script file (use case: [Passing multiple commands to a container in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33979501/1804173)). A [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801587/1804173) is to combine commands with `;` or `&&`, for instance:

```sh
bash -c " \
echo \"Hello World\" ; \
ls -la ; \
run_some_command "
```

In practice writing bash scripts like that turns out to be error prone, because I often forget the semicolon leading to subtle bugs.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27012174/1804173), I was experiment with writing scripts in a more standard style by using a heredoc:

```sh
bash <<EOF
echo "Hello World"
ls -la
run_some_command
EOF
```

---

Unfortunately, I noticed that there is a difference in exit code error handling when using a heredoc. For instance:

```sh
bash -c " \
run_non_existing_command ; \
echo $? "
```

outputs (note that `$?` properly captures the exit code):

```
bash: run_non_existing_command: command not found
127
```

whereas

```sh
bash <<EOF
run_non_existing_command
echo $?
EOF
```

outputs (note that `$?` fails to capture the exit code compared to standard script execution):

```
bash: line 1: run_non_existing_command: command not found
0
```

Why is the heredoc version behaving differently? Is it possible to write the script in the heredoc style and maintaining normal exit code handling?

Comment: `for instance:` - your instance doesn't combine commands (at least not in a way I define "combine"), it runs `bash -c echo "Hello World"` and then runs `ls -la` and `run_some_command`, all in parent shell. I think you are missing \ slashes

Comment: @KamilCuk Correct fixed, thanks! Copy paste mistake, when deploying to Kubernetes the `\` are handled via YAML multi line strings... The observations should still be valid.

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. Probably the same thing would be `bash -c "echo \"Hello World\" ; ls -la ;  run_some_command ;"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is the heredoc version behaving differently?

Because `$?` is expanded before running the command.

The following will output 1, that is the exit status of `false` command:

```
false
bash <<EOF
run_non_existing_command
echo $?
EOF
```

It's the same in principle as the following, which will print `5`:

```
variable=5
bash <<EOF
variable="This is ignored"
echo $variable
EOF
```

> Is it possible to write the script in the heredoc style and maintaining normal exit code handling?

If you want to have the `$?` expanded inside the subshell, then:

```
bash <<EOF
run_non_existing_command
echo \$?
EOF
```

or

```
bash <<'EOF'
run_non_existing_command
echo $?
EOF
```

Also note that:

```
bash -c \
run_non_existing_command ;
echo $? ;
```

is just equal to:

```
bash -c run_non_existing_command
echo $?
```

The `echo $?` is not executed inside `bash -c`.

Comment: Interesting, is there a simple explanation why quoting the `EOF` gets rid of the necessity to escape the `$?`?

Comment: Yes, it was designed this way. See [posix shell 2.7.4 Here-Document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) `If any character in word is quoted, .... the here-document lines shall not be expanded.`